# Programmatically change a xml-created view

Tags: android, xml, view

Is there a way to get the parameters from a XML view, modify some stuff on it and then use it as content view ?

Let's say I have a normal LinearLayout and I want to make that work:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
setContentView(layout);
```

Instead of :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: and by Pragmatically you mean programatically, i assume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

To be more specific, we need more specific info from you.

**Edit**

You can, for example, do the following.
Say you have in your xml specification a TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you want to center horizontal the TextView programmatically:

```
setContentView(R.id.main);
TextView myTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytv);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myTV.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
myTV.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You just set the contentview at the start, and don't need to set it again when you change the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do anyything you want to the layouts even after setContentView. When you do operations like add items to a layout or set a background, the views in the screen are redrawn.

onCreate method is where you can modify layouts as it it about to begin drawing on to a screen.